# Find all the first names in an XML

Tags: xml, t-sql

Microsoft practice database called AdvantureWorks2012 has a table called HumanResources.JobCandidate. That table has several columns. One of those columns is of a uri datatype. This is what's inside one of the cells in that column:

```
<ns:Resume xmlns:ns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/Resume">
  <ns:Name>
    <ns:Name.Prefix></ns:Name.Prefix>
    <ns:Name.First>Shai</ns:Name.First>
    <ns:Name.Middle></ns:Name.Middle>
    <ns:Name.Last>Bassli</ns:Name.Last>
    <ns:Name.Suffix></ns:Name.Suffix>
  </ns:Name>
  <ns:Skills>
I am an experienced and versatile machinist who can operate a range of machinery personally as well as supervise the work of other machinists. I specialize in diagnostics and precision inspection, have expertise in reading blueprints, and am able to call on strong interpersonal and communication skills to guide the work of other production machinists whose work I am called upon to inspect. 
My degree in mechanical engineering affords me a better theoretical understanding and mathematical background than many other candidates in the machinist trade.
    </ns:Skills>
  <ns:Employment>
    <ns:Emp.StartDate>2000-06-01Z</ns:Emp.StartDate>
    <ns:Emp.EndDate>2002-09-30Z</ns:Emp.EndDate>
    <ns:Emp.OrgName>Wingtip Toys</ns:Emp.OrgName>
    <ns:Emp.JobTitle>Lead Machinist</ns:Emp.JobTitle>
    <ns:Emp.Responsibility> Supervised work of staff of four machinists. Coordinated all complex assembly and tooling activities, including production of tricycles and wagons.
Developed parts fabrication from sample parts, drawings and verbal orders.Worked with ISO9000 implementation.
        </ns:Emp.Responsibility>
    <ns:Emp.FunctionCategory>Production</ns:Emp.FunctionCategory>
    <ns:Emp.IndustryCategory>Manufacturing</ns:Emp.IndustryCategory>
    <ns:Emp.Location>
      <ns:Location>
        <ns:Loc.CountryRegion>US </ns:Loc.CountryRegion>
        <ns:Loc.State>MI </ns:Loc.State>
        <ns:Loc.City>Saginaw</ns:Loc.City>
      </ns:Location>
    </ns:Emp.Location>
  </ns:Employment>
  <ns:Employment>
    <ns:Emp.StartDate>1996-11-15Z</ns:Emp.StartDate>
    <ns:Emp.EndDate>2000-05-01Z</ns:Emp.EndDate>
    <ns:Emp.OrgName>Blue Yonder Airlines</ns:Emp.OrgName>
    <ns:Emp.JobTitle>Machinist</ns:Emp.JobTitle>
    <ns:Emp.Responsibility>Repaired and maintained a variety of production and fabrication machine tools.
Set up and operated machines to close tolerances. Used and wrote CNC machine programs. Trained extensively in computer-aided manufacturing.
        </ns:Emp.Responsibility>
    <ns:Emp.FunctionCategory>Production</ns:Emp.FunctionCategory>
    <ns:Emp.IndustryCategory>Manufacturing</ns:Emp.IndustryCategory>
    <ns:Emp.Location>
      <ns:Location>
        <ns:Loc.CountryRegion>US </ns:Loc.CountryRegion>
        <ns:Loc.State>IL </ns:Loc.State>
        <ns:Loc.City>Chicago</ns:Loc.City>
      </ns:Location>
    </ns:Emp.Location>
  </ns:Employment>
  <ns:Employment>
    <ns:Emp.StartDate>1994-06-10Z</ns:Emp.StartDate>
    <ns:Emp.EndDate>1996-07-22Z</ns:Emp.EndDate>
    <ns:Emp.OrgName>City Power and Light</ns:Emp.OrgName>
    <ns:Emp.JobTitle>Assistant Machinist</ns:Emp.JobTitle>
    <ns:Emp.Responsibility>Performed centerless grinding. Received training in manual mill and lathe machines, as well as micrometers and calipers.
Owned complete toolset.Worked extensive overtime on request. </ns:Emp.Responsibility>
    <ns:Emp.FunctionCategory>Production</ns:Emp.FunctionCategory>
    <ns:Emp.IndustryCategory>Manufacturing</ns:Emp.IndustryCategory>
    <ns:Emp.Location>
      <ns:Location>
        <ns:Loc.CountryRegion>US </ns:Loc.CountryRegion>
        <ns:Loc.State>IA </ns:Loc.State>
        <ns:Loc.City>Des Moines</ns:Loc.City>
      </ns:Location>
    </ns:Emp.Location>
  </ns:Employment>
  <ns:Education>
    <ns:Edu.Level>Bachelor</ns:Edu.Level>
    <ns:Edu.StartDate>1990-09-15Z</ns:Edu.StartDate>
    <ns:Edu.EndDate>1994-05-10Z</ns:Edu.EndDate>
    <ns:Edu.Degree>Bachelor of Science</ns:Edu.Degree>
    <ns:Edu.Major>Mechanical Engineering</ns:Edu.Major>
    <ns:Edu.Minor></ns:Edu.Minor>
    <ns:Edu.GPA>3.2</ns:Edu.GPA>
    <ns:Edu.GPAScale>4</ns:Edu.GPAScale>
    <ns:Edu.School>Midwest State University</ns:Edu.School>
    <ns:Edu.Location>
      <ns:Location>
        <ns:Loc.CountryRegion>US </ns:Loc.CountryRegion>
        <ns:Loc.State>IA </ns:Loc.State>
        <ns:Loc.City>Ames</ns:Loc.City>
      </ns:Location>
    </ns:Edu.Location>
  </ns:Education>
  <ns:Address>
    <ns:Addr.Type>Home</ns:Addr.Type>
    <ns:Addr.Street>567 3rd Ave</ns:Addr.Street>
    <ns:Addr.Location>
      <ns:Location>
        <ns:Loc.CountryRegion>US </ns:Loc.CountryRegion>
        <ns:Loc.State>MI </ns:Loc.State>
        <ns:Loc.City>Saginaw</ns:Loc.City>
      </ns:Location>
    </ns:Addr.Location>
    <ns:Addr.PostalCode>53900</ns:Addr.PostalCode>
    <ns:Addr.Telephone>
      <ns:Telephone>
        <ns:Tel.Type>Voice</ns:Tel.Type>
        <ns:Tel.IntlCode>1</ns:Tel.IntlCode>
        <ns:Tel.AreaCode>276</ns:Tel.AreaCode>
        <ns:Tel.Number>555-0114</ns:Tel.Number>
      </ns:Telephone>
      <ns:Telephone>
        <ns:Tel.Type>Fax</ns:Tel.Type>
        <ns:Tel.IntlCode>1</ns:Tel.IntlCode>
        <ns:Tel.AreaCode>276</ns:Tel.AreaCode>
        <ns:Tel.Number>555-0132</ns:Tel.Number>
      </ns:Telephone>
    </ns:Addr.Telephone>
  </ns:Address>
  <ns:EMail>Shai@Example.com</ns:EMail>
  <ns:WebSite></ns:WebSite>
</ns:Resume>
```

I need to find all first and last names in this column suing tsql. I am just a beginner, so an elaborate explanation would go long ways. Thanks.

Comment: Using TSQL or what??

Comment: @Oscar 
Sorry, good point. I am using tsql. Question was fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step, register default namespace URI (this part of your XML : `xmlns="..."`) :

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/Resume')
```

then you can use `value()` method on the XML column passing XQuery as first parameter and SQL data type as the second, for example :

```
Resume.value('(/Resume/Name/Name.First)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS 'First'
```

Above XQuery/Xpath break down :

- `(....)[1]` : Get the first result of the inner XQuery/XPath (the `....` part).
- `/Resume/Name/Name.First` : In this case, the XQuery/XPath used is just a simple path expression, like file/folder path in our PC. But instead of expressing file/folder location within storage, this XPath/XQuery expresses XML node location within the entire XML document.

Complete query example looks about like this :

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/Resume')

select 
  Resume.value('(/Resume/Name/Name.First)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS 'First',
  Resume.value('(/Resume/Name/Name.Last)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS 'Last'
from HumanResources.JobCandidate
```

For Reference :

- [MSDN: `value()` Method (xml Data Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx)
- [MSDN: Add Namespaces to Queries with WITH XMLNAMESPACES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx)